Telnetlib - how to use this?
I am writing a script in python that first of all connects to a local switch serially before (hopefully) telnetting to remote switches. I run some commands locally and remotely. But I cannot get through my local switch using telnetlib, it hangs up on connecting and I can only imagine it’s the way I’m using it.
Is it something to do with my initial serial connection? What state should my local switch be in when I use telnetlib?

You should probably use a library like pexpect to automate control of an interactive telnet session.

Will give pexpect a try
